# Spark, add new Column with the same value in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some problem with the `withColumn` function in Spark-Scala environment.
I would like to add a new Column in my DataFrame like that:

```
+---+----+---+
|  A|   B|  C|
+---+----+---+
|  4|blah|  2|
|  2|    |  3|
| 56| foo|  3|
|100|null|  5|
+---+----+---+
```

became:

```
+---+----+---+-----+
|  A|   B|  C|  D  |
+---+----+---+-----+
|  4|blah|  2|  750|
|  2|    |  3|  750|
| 56| foo|  3|  750|
|100|null|  5|  750|
+---+----+---+-----+
```

the column D in one value repeated N-time for each row in my DataFrame.

The code are this:

```
var totVehicles : Double = df_totVehicles(0).getDouble(0); //return 750
```

The variable totVehicles returns the correct value, it's works!

The second DataFrame has to calculate 2 fields (id_zipcode, n_vehicles), and add the third column (with the same value -750):

```
var df_nVehicles =
df_carPark.filter(
      substring($"id_time",1,4) < 2013
    ).groupBy(
      $"id_zipcode"
    ).agg(
      sum($"n_vehicles") as 'n_vehicles
    ).select(
      $"id_zipcode" as 'id_zipcode,
      'n_vehicles
    ).orderBy(
      'id_zipcode,
      'n_vehicles
    );
```

Finally, I add the new column with `withColumn` function:

```
var df_nVehicles2 = df_nVehicles.withColumn(totVehicles, df_nVehicles("n_vehicles") + df_nVehicles("id_zipcode"))
```

But Spark returns me this error:

```
 error: value withColumn is not a member of Unit
         var df_nVehicles2 = df_nVehicles.withColumn(totVehicles, df_nVehicles("n_vehicles") + df_nVehicles("id_zipcode"))
```

Can you help me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`lit` function is for adding literal values as a column

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("D", lit(750))
```